# Calculate Scroll Position using vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

The wrapper overflows on x direction so it has horizontal scrolling, and the table inside .body overflows on y direction so it has vertical scrolling. The Markup looks like below.

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="head">
            <table>...</table>
        </div>
        <div class="body">
            <table>...</table>        
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've removed the default browser scrollbars and created custom `scrollbars`. The custom scrollbars are created for the container element. When wrapper scrolls horizontally then container's `x-scrollbar` scrolls, and when table inside body scrolls vertically then container's y-scrollbar scrolls.

The problem is with the vertical scrollbar. When I click and drag and the vertical scrollbar's thumb, I've to update the `scrollTop` of the table inside body. I'm founding it hard to figure out the right calculations to update the `scrollTop`.? Someone help me fix this.

I've set up the `mousedown`, `mousemove` and `mouseup` listeners for the y-scrollbar's thumb to calculate the amount of distance dragged, but how do I calculate the `scrollTop` of the table inside body with respect to the amount of distance dragged in the `y-scrollbar`?

Comment: Use an event handler like `addEventListener('scroll', function(e) { ... });` An example on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/scroll_event . Do the smae with event 'touchmove' for iOS.

Comment: Scroll event handlers are already setup and they are functioning perfectly. Now I'm working on the click and drag of scrollbar thumb to update the scroll.

Comment: What about $(document).scrollTop()

Comment: Sorry mate. I'm working in pure vanilla js without jquery or any other third party libraries. Suggest me an pure js workaround for this.

Comment: Are you asking what value you should set the "scrollTop" property to? Wouldn't that just be the percentage you move the scrollbar * the height of your table? Instead of finding the difference in position that your scrollbar is dragged, find its position relative to its moving height and then use that percentage to find the amount of pixels you need to offset in your table

Comment: No. I figured out the right way to calculate this and I've posted that as a answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the correct calculations.

```
var elem = document.querySelector('.body table'); // Content to be scrolled.
var yTrack = document.querySelector('.track.y'); // scroll-track-y
var yBar = yTrack.querySelector('.bar'); // scroll-thumb-y
```

On `mousedown` event, I'm setting the intial values to an object.
On `mousemove` event, I'm updating the `scrollTop` of the element to be scrolled.
Then on `mouseup` event i'm setting that object to null.

```
function yBar_OnMouseDown(e)
{
    initCoords = {
        axis: 'y',
        abs: e.pageY,
        bar: yBar,
        p0: yBar.offsetTop
    };
};

function yBar_OnMouseMove(e)
{
    if (initCoords && initCoords.axis === 'y')
    {
        var maxElemScroll = elem.scrollHeight - elem.clientHeight;
        var room = yTrack.scrollHeight - yBar.clientHeight;
        var diff = e.pageY - initCoords.abs;
        var abs = initCoords.p0 + diff;
        var maxTrackScroll = yTrack.offsetHeight - yBar.offsetHeight;

        abs = abs < 0 ? 0 : maxTrackScroll < abs ? maxTrackScroll : abs;
        elem.scrollTop = maxElemScroll * abs / room;
    }
};

function yBar_OnMouseUp(e)
{
    initCoords = null;
};
```